# Solving for $x$ from given equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Sorry for the trivial question. I was wondering if there was an easy way to solve this equation.
The equation is:

$$(x-1)(x-2)(x+3)(x-6)+36=0$$

I know this can be solved the traditional way, where after multiplying all terms, we could factorize the entire thing, but I ended up with a really messy equation. Is there a simpler method I'm missing?

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: Hint. The fact that the constants in the parentheses are factors of $36$ suggests trying $x =?$

Comment: Please remember to include a source and motivation for your questions. *Where* did you encounter this equation and *why* would you want to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
(x-1)(x-2)(x+3)(x-6)+36&=0\\
(x^2-3x+2)(x^2-3x-18)+36&=0\\
(x^2-3x)^2-16(x^2-3x)&=0\\
(x^2-3x)(x^2-3x-16)&=0\\
x&=0, 3\textrm{ or }\frac{3\pm\sqrt{73}}{2}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 5):

We have
$$
-(x-1)(x-2)(x+3)(x-6)=36,
$$
but $36=2^23^2$, so we can easily list the integer solutions, namely $x=0$ and $x=3$.

Answer (score 2):

For more 'complicated' numbers you have to open up the brackets and factorise, however in this case, due to its simple nature, I tried to randomly substitute $x$ by some simple numbers to see if any of them satisfy the equation.

The first two numbers I tried coincidentally worked: $x=0$ and $x=3$. Check for the other two roots yourself, they are probably small integer numbers such as these.

Answer (score 1):

$(x-1)(x-2)(x+3)(x-6)+36$

$=(x-1)(x-6)(x-2)(x+3)+36$

$=(x^2-7x+6)(x^2+x-6)+36$

$=(x^2-3x-4x+6)(x^2-3x+4x-6)+36$

$=(x^2-3x)^2-(4x-6)^2+36$

$=(x^2-3x)^2-((4x-6)^2-6^2)$

$=(x^2-3x)^2-(4x-6+6)(4x-6-6)$

$=(x^2-3x)^2-4x(4x-12)$

$=x^2\times (x-3)^2-16x(x-3)$

$=(x-3)(x^2(x-3)-16x)$

$=(x-3)(x^3-3x^2-16x)$

$=x(x-3)(x^2-3x-16)$

It's a bit hard to find non-integer solutions for $x^2-3x-16$, but I will explain the rest:

- The strategy is to make (part of) the expression equivalent to the equality $(A-B)(A+B)=A^2-B^2$.
- For the lines $3$, $4$, $5$, to identify which is $A$ and which is $B$, we will take the "average" expression and put it $A$, by adding two expressions together and divided by $2$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a simpler method of solving the equation without multiplying all the terms and then factorize. Either stick to the traditional way, or use the GDC :)

Comment: The other answers have shown a simpler method, essentially guess and check.  The structure of the problem leads to a few guesses, two of which work.